# How to get clear voice after decoding base64 audiodata string in php

Tags: php, ios, swift, audio

I developed a demo application for to upload audio file from ios application to server.

Bellow is my swift code to convert audiofile data into base64 string

```
let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/development/uploadAudio.php")

    let path:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentDirectory: AnyObject = path.object(at: 0) as AnyObject
    var fileName = "audio.mp3"

    filePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)
    print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(filePath)"))
    var fileData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    var data:String = (fileData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))



    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let post:NSString = "subjective=\(data)"  as NSString

    let postData:Data = post.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    let postLength:NSString = String(postData.count) as NSString
    request.httpBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    _ = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        if error != nil{

        print("error is : \(error!)")

        }

        print("Response is : \(responseString!)")




    })
    task.resume()
```

In php I get value of this data in php 
in bellow code

```
public function saveRecordedVoice()
{

  $audio = $_POST['data'];
  $decoded = base64_decode($audio);
  $file_location = "assets/records/recorded_audio.mp3";

  $success = file_put_contents($file_location, $decoded);

  if($success){
     echo "File Saved";
  }else{
    echo "Uh-uh!";
  }

}
```

Here i saved data in respective folder file as "recorded_audio.mp3"
but when i play this file in audio player i didn't get clear voice audio file.
How can i do that.